# webservice source in web.xml

Tags: web-services, tomcat, netbeans, web.xml

How I can get my web service client (in a web application) uses the web.xml file to get the source of the wsdl?

I am using netbeans 6.9 and tomcat, and so far we have in our web application a web services references with the url of the wsdl.

Answer (score 0):

If it must be the web.xml, you can configure a context parameter(like any other) like:

```
   <context-param>
    <param-name>webservice.Location</param-name>
    <param-value>http://theaddress:8080/webapp?wsdl</param-value>
   </context-param>
```

After configuring as above (the `Webservice.Location`) is an arbitrary variable name you can change to suit your needs. If you're not using any add-on web application layers like JSF or Struts etc, you can now reference this variable(from the `HttpServletRequest` object)  like so in a servlet

```
        String webServiceAddr = request.getServletContext().getInitParameter("webservice.Location"); //getServletContext() will give you an instance to a ServletContext object which basically is a representation of your entire web application deployment environment including configuration files.
```

The variable `webServiceAddr` will now contain the configured value

I advise though you externalise such a config to a standard `.properties` file as it's a little bit risky having a deployer mucking about with other configurations in your web.xml while trying to set it up. It's also best practice in configuration management for applications. A small tutorial on properties files [here](http://jaitechwriteups.blogspot.com/2007/01/how-to-read-properties-file-in-web.html)

Comment: I must do it in the web.xml, but do not know how to use what you have posted, I have understood that it is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend to store such resources in `web.xml`, because they can be changed in future. For e.g. if the web service which is deployed in `http://theaddress:8080/webapp?wsdl` will be migrated to some other server and URL will change. Then you have to modify your application in which case it is not very efficient way.

I would suggest [JNDI](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html) to store resource like this. Read [how to do this](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html) in `Tomcat`, it is not hard to set up.

The alternative is to use `.properties` files, but I'd rather choose `JNDI` over `.properties`.